# correcly using allow_disk_usage with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

I have an object that run fine for smaller collections, however my collection is big with over about 7 million documents. I am essentially trying to group by key, key1 and key2

```
def groupByThreeItems(self, db=None, col=None, key=None, key1=None, key2=None):
    coll=self.client_()[db][col]
    
    agg_result= coll.aggregate([{
       '$group':
         {'_id': { key: "$"+key, key1: "$"+key1},
           key2: { "$push":  "$"+key2 }, "Count":{"$sum": 1}
         }}],{'allow_disk_use': True})
    return [i for i in agg_result]
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'
```

However, when I do not use the allow_disk_use, I get following error.

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", 'code': 292, 'codeName': 'QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed'}
```

**How do I solve the disk usage error to allow me use the aggregation framework?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `allowDiskUse`

```
agg_result= coll.aggregate([..query], allowDiskUse=True)
```

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=allowDiskUse#pymongo.database.Database.aggregate

> All optional aggregate command parameters should be passed as keyword arguments to this method. Valid options include, but are not limited to:

> allowDiskUse (bool): Enables writing to temporary files. When set to True, aggregation stages can write data to the _tmp subdirectory of the –dbpath directory. The default is False.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate

> allowDiskUse  boolean
> Optional. Enables writing to temporary files. When set to true, aggregation operations can write data to the _tmp subdirectory in the dbPath directory. See Perform Large Sort Operation with External Sort for an example.

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the profiler log messages and diagnostic log messages includes a usedDisk indicator if any aggregation stage wrote data to temporary files due to memory restrictions.

Comment: With that, it seems allowDiskUse works but spills memory limit error with $push. pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes', 'code': 146, 'codeName': 'ExceededMemoryLimit'}  . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html#memory-restrictions . Wondering if there are other ways to optimize the query?

Comment: @lpt you've to  `$limit` the number of records you perform an operation on, you can move your logic to the python code. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html#memory-restrictions

Comment: Actually, thanks Tushar, with limit the query is more optimized and at least ran without any error. There might be some hacky way to circumvent this memory limit when the collections are millions?

Comment: @lpt adding indexes might help if you've sort stages, skip, and limit. You can try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/ to divide your aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to aggregate is session. You need to pass options as keyword arguments and reference the documentation for the correct option name to use:

```
agg_result= coll.aggregate([...],allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: I get this if that argument is used. pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unrecognized field 'allow_disk_use',